# How to delete a file while some other thread is writing into it?

Tags: c#, file-io

I am getting IOException whenever I try to use File.Delete method on a file into which some other thread is writing. I don't have control over the writing thread. So from my thread how can I stop the file writing and delete the file.

Comment: I think you won't be happy if your program is operating a file while someone's process kills yours and delete your file.

Comment: Do you have control over the code in that other thread? What does it look like?

Comment: ya Danny I wont be for sure...bt welcome to this software writing..this kinda ugly requirements do come up I guess.

Comment: @Fredrik I dont have much control over the other thread.

Comment: You may be able to rename the file, but not delete it.

Comment: You should reconsider your approach, It smells like a bad design..

Comment: @Danish is right. If you don't have control over the other thread then what is it doing running in what I presume is *your* appdomain? You should never have an out-of-control thread in your appdomain; if you cannot control a thread then that thread should be running in its own appdomain, or even better, in its own process, where it can be safely killed if necessary.

Answer (score 4):

You can't; that's the whole point of file locking - to prevent precisely what you are proposing.

The only way you can possibly achieve the same effect is to kill the other process first. That's a really bad design, and it may not be acceptable at all for you to do.

Why do you need to do this, anyway?

Answer (score 0):

For this to be possible, the writing thread has to open the file in a non-exclusive mode that would allow access to the file to others.

If you have no control whatsoever on the writing thread, you won't be able to do it.

A potential alternative is to try to get the same handle that is being used for writing. After all if it's a thread in your application then this handle is somewhere in your memory space.

Remember that if you do manage to delete the file, the other thread might not expect it and if it doesn't handle the exception it will get when trying to write again, your entire process may be terminated.

Seriously it sounds like you should reconsider your design.

Answer (score 0):

Simply , that is not possible since some other process is having exclusive lock on the file while writing and forcefully , you can not acquire lock.

So either your process has to wait until locking process releases the lock or somehow kill the locking process.

Answer (score 0):

Some other *thread*? I.e. in your own program?

Communicate to it that something has come up and it needs to stop writing, close the file and delete it. Then let it respond to the message and do so.